# Can't install bleeding edge CMake package

Tags: cmake, opensuse

I need the freshest CMake installed on my OpenSuse in order to use an app. I'm trying to download it from the official site and follow the instructions: https://cmake.org/install/
However, I get the following errors:

```
aleksandr@linux-b0ak:~/Downloads/cmake-3.17.0-rc1> cmake .
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/aleksandr/Downloads/cmake-3.17.0-rc1/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/aleksandr/Downloads/cmake-3.17.0-rc1/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

```
aleksandr@linux-b0ak:~/Downloads/cmake-3.17.0-rc1> ./bootstrap 
---------------------------------------------
CMake 3.17.0-rc1, Copyright 2000-2020 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
C compiler on this system is: cc   
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Cannot find a C++ compiler that supports both C++11 and the specified C++ flags.
Please specify one using environment variable CXX.
The C++ flags are "".
They can be changed using the environment variable CXXFLAGS.
See cmake_bootstrap.log for compilers attempted.
---------------------------------------------
Log of errors: /home/aleksandr/Downloads/cmake-3.17.0-rc1/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log
```

Comment: Do you in fact have a C++ compiler installed?

Comment: Thanks, I've installed it just now, tried to run ./bootstrap again. Got an error:

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have it. I've just installed it, tried to run ./bootstrap again. I got the following message: ```-- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Error at Utilities/cmcurl/CMakeLists.txt:454 (message):
  Could not find OpenSSL.  Install an OpenSSL development package or
  configure CMake with -DCMAKE_USE_OPENSSL=OFF to build without OpenSSL.
```

Comment: It seems that i have the package openssl installed already, so I can't figure out what to do next.

Comment: Try installing `libssl-dev`.

Comment: Note "OpenSSL **development** package".  On many distributions, the main package for a library doesn't contain the header files and other stuff needed to compile programs that use the library.  Those are often in a separate "development" package.  I don't know about openSUSE but there appear to be packages called `libopenssl-devel-64bit` and `-32bit`; one of those may be what you need.

Comment: I did install the library. Than I proceed to installing cmake. After that I tried to run it, bun no success ```aleksandr@linux-b0ak:~/Downloads/cmake-3.17.0-rc1> cmake --version
bash: /usr/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It seems like cmake has been installed to /usr/local/share/cmake-3.17.
How do I run it from there?